# QuickBooks Online Apps - countries supported

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

I can't see anywhere in the Intuit Partner Platform documentation that explains which countries my app will be available in or the limitations of the versions used in international countries.

I've been told by a QuickBooks Online sales rep that "not all programs that work in the US version application center will work in international countries."

I'm specifically interested in knowing if users from Canada, Jamaica, the UK, India, and Australia can use my app if it is published on the Intuit App Center here in the US.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intuit Partner Platform and Intuit Anywhere works ONLY with USA versions of QuickBooks. Period, end of story.

Intuit has indicated they are working on internationalization, but haven't given any timelines on that yet.

Sooo...

> I'm specifically interested in knowing if users from Canada, Jamaica, the UK, India, and Australia can use my app if it is published on the Intuit App Center here in the US.

No, they won't be able to.

Answer (score 3):

At this time, IPP only supports apps that integrate with QuickBooks Online (QBO) for the US market. However, we do plan to enable developers who want to integrate with QBO for customers outside of the US where QBO becomes available.

This is a high priority for Intuit and IPP and we'll share our detailed roadmap with the developer community ASAP. In the meantime, you can register for today's webinar here http://ippblog.intuit.com/blog/2013/02/registration-for-ipp-quickbooks-api-v3-webinar-.html that provides the roadmap for the IPP QuickBooks API including some details on global readiness.

regards,
Jarred

Answer (score 1):

Update with regards to QBO v3 API.

The QBO v3 API supports every country that has a QuickBooks Online version.

Reference: https://intuitpartnerplatform.lc.intuit.com/questions/902695-total-list-of-countries-supported-for-qbo-v3-api