# Australian API Availablility

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

Followup to this question -
[QuickBooks Online Apps - countries supported](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14983571/176868)

I have been told by a Intuit employee that "There are a lot of shared elements between the US and Global APIs. US is on v2 services…AU is on v3"...which to me implies that V3 is now available.

How do you make API calls to an Australian online instance? The web interface of my trial instance is @ https://sg.qbo.intuit.com

I am trying to use the API explorer as per https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0010_getting_started/0007_firstrequest to connect to this version. Step 3.7 is failing with an "Unable to connect to the remote server" error. Maybe this is because the API explorer only supports V2?

I am trying to follow up with the contact @ Intuit and will update the question if I hear back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

V3 is not generally available at this time. See http://ippblog.intuit.com/blog/2013/04/quickbooks-api-v3-april-release.html for more details.

Here is a webinar on V3 - http://ippblog.intuit.com/blog/2013/02/quickbooks-api-v3-webinar-recording.html

Comment: Thanks. Any dates for V3 public release?

Comment: We have not announced the dates for a public release, however if you are a registered Intuit Partner Platform developer we will notify you via email when the service is available.